# How do I fix GitHub icons (octicons) on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, icons, github

Ever since GitHub added [octicons](https://github.com/blog/1106-say-hello-to-octicons), I have been unable to see them in Firefox. I found the UTF codes listed [here](https://github.com/styleguide/css/7.0), but I have no idea how to fix them.

[image: GitHub octicons on Firefox]

Comment: Go to `about:config` and check if `gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled` is set to `false`. You seem to be having an issue with webfonts, I guess.

Comment: On second thought, your normal text isn't rendered properly as well. The font for those labels should be sans-serif.

Comment: Changing the boolean made no difference.

Comment: Any other guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go into `Firefox` / `Preferences` / `Content` / `Fonts & Colors` / `Advanced...` and check `Allow pages to choose their own fonts, instead of my selections above`.

I didn't even remember that I had this setting unchecked. I remember doing it because Google search results would always be italicized or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I whitelisted fastly.net in NoScript. If you are using NoScript or a similar browser extension that can block third party websites, be sure to enable fastly.net because GitHub seems to have started to use this domain to distribute various assets including CSS and JavaScript code as well as some logos and perhaps the Octicons font they use for icons.

Comment: I am not using NoScript, any other suggestions?

Comment: This solved my problem, but it wasn't fastly.net it was GitHub itself being blocked.