# How do I fix custom font icons on Firefox (again)?

Tags: firefox, fonts, icons

Using my answer [from this question](https://superuser.com/questions/616861/how-do-i-fix-github-icons-octicons-on-firefox), I once-upon-a-time fixed this issue in Firefox where I was unable to see custom font icons. Sadly, this is now occurring on another Firefox profile of mine, and the fix is not working. Does anyone have any other ideas on how to fix these icons?

[image: GitHub icons missing]

[image: Ancestry.com icons missing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At some point in time, I set `gfx.downloadable_fonts.enabled` in about:config to `false` instead of `true`. I'm guessing I tried this as a solution to my first question on the same issue. I actually didn't figure this out until I accidentally deleted my prefs.js lol.